# vstest.console.exe with ClassName as /testcasefilter

Tags: vstest.console

I am looking for executing the unit test by ClassName using vstes.console.exe, any help

I tried like

```
/TestCaseFilter:"ClassName=ProgressTests"
```

but that throws this error:

> Error: No tests matched the filter because it contains one or more
> properties that are not valid (ClassName). Specify filter expression
> containing valid properties (TestCategory, Priority,
> FullyQualifiedName, Name) and try again.

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can run the tests by specifying the fully qualified class name:

```
vstest.console MyBusinessDomain.Tests.dll /testcasefilter:FullyQualifiedName~MyBusinessDomain.Tests.Shopping.Cart
```

where:

`MyBusinessDomain.Tests.dll` is the test dll

`MyBusinessDomain.Tests.Shopping.Cart` is the fully qualified class name

Or you can run the tests classes by namespace:

```
vstest.console MyBusinessDomain.Tests.dll /testcasefilter:FullyQualifiedName~MyBusinessDomain.Tests.Shopping
```

This command will run all the tests under `MyBusinessDomain.Tests.Shopping` namespace.

NOTE: FYI, vstest.console is newer than mstest and is preferred for running via the command line. It can be added to the environment path with this location(for VS2015) :

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow
```

Comment: In Visual Studio 2019 I just tried `vstest path/to/tests.dll /testcasefilter:"ClassName=SomeTestClass"` and it worked just fine. Maybe this support was added back in VS 2019?

Comment: Actually it was `/testcasefilter:ClassName~SomeTestClass` (~ not =)

Comment: Is there away to specify the sequential order in which tests should run?

Answer (score 5):

According to https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vikramagrawal/2012/07/23/running-selective-unit-tests-in-vs-2012-rc-using-testcasefilter/ - "ClassName is only valid for unit tests for Windows store apps, currently not available for classic MSTest" although that blog post is from years ago now though.

You could just use the FullyQualifiedName filter type as in /testcasefilter:FullyQualifiedName~NameSpace.Class

Answer (score 2):

The tilda `~` means "contains", so if `Foobar` is the name of your class:

```
vstest.console bin\Debug\MyTests.dll /TestCaseFilter:FullyQualifiedName~Foobar
```

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155800.aspx